# React Router Cannot GET / Error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After reading most of the similar issues in here about my problem, I still didn't find the answer.

I am using material-ui for UI design, and I am trying to add Links on the Drawer, but the links giving me Cannot GET Error. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';


const style = {
  backgroundColor: "#EF413D",
  marginRight: 20,
  width: 40,
};

export default class DrawerLeft extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
        this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
      }

      //This handles the closing event
      handleClose() {this.setState({open: false});}
      //This handles the opening event
      handleToggle() { this.setState({open: !this.state.open}); } 


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FloatingActionButton onClick={this.handleToggle} mini={true}>
            <ContentAdd style={style} />
        </FloatingActionButton>
        <Drawer
          docked={false}
          width={400}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>
          <IndexLink>
                <Link to="./HomePage">Home</Link>
          </IndexLink>
          </MenuItem>

          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>
            <IndexLink>
              <Link to="./About">About</Link>
            </IndexLink>
          </MenuItem>

          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>
            <IndexLink>
                <Link to="./Rates">Rates</Link>
            </IndexLink>
          </MenuItem>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried changing IndexLink to Router or Route, same with Link but it gave me more errors.

Comment: At some place you're going to need to create a `Router` and some `Route`s that specify what component should be rendered for each path.

Comment: Is it possible to create a const containing the Router?